# Adding new contact with seperate names

Tags: java, android, flutter, plugins

I am trying to add a contact in Android (Flutter plugin), but before I add the contact, I want to give the user the option to edit some data if needed.

For that I used the ContactsContract module.

Because in The Netherlands we have a weird naming scheme (our names CAN be divided in three different sections: Firstname + Between (tussenvoegsel) + Lastname) I want to manually give the first name, and the last name.

For that reason I have this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
// intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Firstname Between Lastname");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

As you might have seen, I insert some data:

```
ContentValues row3 = new ContentValues();
row3.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row3.put(StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, "Middel naam");
row3.put(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Familie naam");
row3.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "TEST");
data.add(row3);
```

I have this with a example e-mail that is added the same way, but my result is that all the name fields are empty.

[image: screenshot phone]

We really need this "edit" functionality in native Android and I cannot figure out why the fields are not entered properly.